# itertools.izip() for not predefined count of lists

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following data structure: `{'one':['a','b','c'],'two':['q','w','e'],'three':['t','u','y'],...}`. So, the dictionary has variant count of keys. Each array, picked by dict's key has similar length. How I can convert this structure to following: `[{'one':'a','two':'q','three':'t'},{'one':'b','two':'w','three':'y'},...]`?

I think I should use itertools.izip(), but how i can apply it with not predefined count of args? Maybe something like this: `itertools.izip([data[l] for l in data.keys()])`?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment in using [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) is correct but the way of using it is not quite right

You first need to

- get the items as a list of tuples (key, value), (using `iteritems()` method if using Py2.x or `items()` if using Py3.x)
- create a scalar product of key and value
- flatten the list (using itertools.chain)
- zip it (using itertools.izip)
- and then create a dict of each element

Here is the sample code

```
>>> from pprint import PrettyPrinter
>>> pp = PrettyPrinter(indent = 4)
>>> pp.pprint(map(dict, izip(*chain((product([k], v) for k, v in data.items())))))
[   {   'one': 'a', 'three': 't', 'two': 'q'},
    {   'one': 'b', 'three': 'u', 'two': 'w'},
    {   'one': 'c', 'three': 'y', 'two': 'e'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not terribly elegant, but does the trick:

```
In [9]: [{k:v[i] for (k,v) in d.items()} for i in range(len(d.values()[0]))]
Out[9]: 
[{'one': 'a', 'three': 't', 'two': 'q'},
 {'one': 'b', 'three': 'u', 'two': 'w'},
 {'one': 'c', 'three': 'y', 'two': 'e'}]
```

I can't help thinking that there's got to be a better way to phrase the `i` loop, but nothing comes to mind right now.

Alternatively:

```
In [50]: map(dict, zip(*[[(k, v) for v in l] for k, l in d.items()]))
Out[50]: 
[{'one': 'a', 'three': 't', 'two': 'q'},
 {'one': 'b', 'three': 'u', 'two': 'w'},
 {'one': 'c', 'three': 'y', 'two': 'e'}]
```

Not sure if this is much of an improvement on the readability front though.

Comment: `next(iter(d.values()))` is an alternative. Still ugly.